# Cannot use install.packages

Tags: r

Good afternoon ,

I have a problem with install.packages , for example :

```
install.packages("caret")
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib:
  scheme not supported in URL 'cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Mouad/Documents/R/win-library/3.5’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib:
  scheme not supported in URL 'cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘caret’ is not available (for R version 3.5.0)
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5:
  scheme not supported in URL 'cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/PACKAGES'
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/bin/windows/contrib/3.5:
  cannot open URL 'http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/PACKAGES'
```

I tried without success :

```
options(repos='cran.rstudio.com/')
```

I think the source of pb is that Rtools isn´t properly installed :

```
    Sys.which("make")
    make 

  ""
```

Thank you for help !

Comment: I need each time to install dependencies manually , Could someone give a suggestion !

Comment: My guess is that it's because you're on a relatively old version of R. On each package's page on CRAN, they make references to various R-based versioning, e.g., `r-release` (4.1) and `r-oldrel` (4.0.5), so version 3.5 is well behind what they're advertising. There are still versions available under https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/ including 3.5.1 and such, so you may be able to find the packages you need and manually download and install them from file.

Comment: @r2evans ; i don't think this is the reason !

Comment: Try changing your repo to `https://cran.rstudio.com`, explicitly specifying `https://`.

Comment: I think the problem is with the Rtools !

Comment: None of those warnings suggest that Rtools is even touched yet during the install process. If you received warnings or errors about makefiles or gcc not found or similar, then yes, Rtools could be the source of the problem, but you aren't, you're getting "unable to access index", which is well before Rtools enters the process. This could be firewall, network glitch, or perhaps a few other things that are also not related to Rtools (or even specific to R).

Comment: the pb arises Even with R 4.1.0

Comment: As for your `Sys.which("make")` problem, that's clear: fix your `PATH`, read the *"Putting Rtools on the PATH"* section of https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/.

Comment: I removed Rstudio and the installed R versions. I tried again and the pb still occurring. Now Sys.which("make") gives the right output

Comment: I tried to open 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/PACKAGES'¨ manually from firefox without success , however I  can open https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/ that contains tar.gz files

Comment: So the `scheme not supported in URL` really suggests that it wants some kind of URI scheme, yours is missing. Have you tried prepending `https://` to your repos?

Comment: Yes , i tried ! I think they had changed the scheme of their repository and this is exactly the pb ! I think install.packages() is a built-in function so it should work anyway ( I installed now Rtools 4 )

Comment: The preference shift from `http:` to `https:` is not recent, it's been in the works for years. If you can, always use `https:` (there are some exceptions, of course). So you're saying that it is working now?

Comment: There is no problem with https: , I still have the same error

Comment: Even when trying to download directly from link , I have a pb: For example  :  install.packages("https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/jsonlite_1.7.2.tar.gz")

Comment: Your sample code continues to be missing the scheme. When I eval `install.packages("cran.rstudio....")`, it fails, since without a scheme it will look for a local directory named `cran.rstudio.com`, which is unlikely to exist. When I eval `install.packages("https://cran.rstudio...")`, it does not fail.

Comment: Pb still not solved !

Comment: I really don't know. Your question is woefully out of date, so I don't know what you're trying. Your comments include abbreviated code, so again I don't know what you're really running. Further, this question has migrated several times from incorrect-scheme to Rtools-not-found to something completely different, with no identification of what the problems really are. When an install fails, it has error messages. I strongly suggest you [edit] your question and bring it up to date, including actual code and the literal error/warning messages with installing one package.

Comment: @r2evans , me also i found this situation strange ! I will just try to use anaconda instead